# Why does cassandra client driver respond more information than cqlsh

Tags: typescript, cassandra, datastax, cql, cqlsh

I am using [datastax nodejs-driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver) to get information of a keyspace from cassandra.

```
const results = await client.execute( `
    DESC KEYSPACE ${keyspace}
` );
```

The `client.execute` method returns an object includes lots of information:

```
ResultSet {
      info: {
        queriedHost: '127.0.0.1:9042',
        triedHosts: { '127.0.0.1:9042': null },
        speculativeExecutions: 0,
        achievedConsistency: 10,
        traceId: undefined,
        warnings: undefined,
        customPayload: undefined,
        isSchemaInAgreement: true
      },
      rows: [
        Row {
          keyspace_name: 'xxxx',
          type: 'keyspace',
          name: 'xxxx',
          create_statement: "CREATE KEYSPACE xxxx WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;"
        }
      ],
      rowLength: 1,
      columns: [
        { name: 'keyspace_name', type: [Object] },
        { name: 'type', type: [Object] },
        { name: 'name', type: [Object] },
        { name: 'create_statement', type: [Object] }
      ],
      pageState: null,
      nextPage: undefined,
      nextPageAsync: undefined
    }
```

But while execute `DESC KEYSPACE xxxx`, only the `create_statement` part is responded:

```sh
cqlsh> DESC xxxx;

CREATE KEYSPACE xxxx WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
cqlsh>
```

My questions are:

1. Why could client driver provide more information of the results.
2. Can I get the same results by using cqlsh?
3. The result above includes a `Row` property, it's structure looks like something like:

```
interface Row {
    keyspace_name: string;
    type: 'keyspace';
    name: string;
    create_statement: string;
}
```

Where can I find the declarations of different types of `Row`s?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

CQLSH is an interactive user shell, so it responds with a succinct query response in text. The Node.js driver (or Python driver with CQLSH) returns a ResultSet object and is machine readable.  Machine readable results will usually contain a lot of additional information.

CQLSH let's you [enable tracing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html). With tracing you'll get a more verbose level of information.